# Python Beautifulsoup Index out of range in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to scrape with beautifulsoup the list of restaurants in a city and their details (ranking, adress .. )

In the first step I am getting the list of paths to all restaurants and storing them in the variable `mydivs`, and then I am trying to loop on the list and get the details of each resturant, this is my code :

```
for link in mydivs:

    print(link["href"])
    url2=URL = 'https://www.yelp.fr'+link["href"]
    page2 = requests.get(URL)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.text)
    if (len(soup2.find_all("span",{"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__2q4au border-color--default__373c0__YEvMS"}))!=0):
        address=soup2.find_all("p",{"class":"lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_ text-weight--bold__373c0__3HYJa"})
        if (len(address[0].findChildren("span" , recursive=False))==0):
            print("dep"+address[0].findChildren("span" , recursive=False)[0].text)
        else:
            print("dep"+address[0].findChildren("a" , recursive=False)[0].text)

    print("adre"+address[1].findChildren("span" , recursive=False)[0].text)
    print("Beki adress"+soup2.find_all("p",{"class":"lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f text-color--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--left__373c0__2pnx_"})[0].text)
    print("tel"+soup2.find_all("div",{"class":"lemon--div__373c0__1mboc island__373c0__3fs6U u-padding-t1 u-padding-r1 u-padding-b1 u-padding-l1 border--top__373c0__19Owr border--right__373c0__22AHO border--bottom__373c0__uPbXS border--left__373c0__1SjJs border-color--default__373c0__2oFDT background-color--white__373c0__GVEnp"})[0].findChildren("div" , recursive=False)[0].findChildren("div" , recursive=False)[0].findChildren("div" , recursive=False)[1].findChildren("p" , recursive=False)[1].text)
    print("etoile"+soup2.find_all("span",{"class":"lemon--span__373c0__3997G display--inline__373c0__2q4au border-color--default__373c0__YEvMS"})[0].findChildren("div",recursive=False)[0]["aria-label"])
```

and I am getting the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

On line:

```
print("dep"+address[0].findChildren("a" , recursive=False)[0].text)
```

I am strugling to fix this error and I am getting it on the first print always.

Comment: I guess you `findChildren` returns `None` not a list as there is no "a" in the adress object.

Comment: @Fourier, it'd return an empty list. If it returned `None` the error would be `NoneType is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above comment .If there is no anchor tags inside the page then it will return "index out of range exception".

You can verify the same by below code
x = soup.findAll("a")

```
 if x is not None and len(x) > 0:  
   section = x[0]
```

if above returns None then there is no a tags in the page.